# Using dynamic key and value in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Terraform allows for [Dynamic Blocks](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks), which is like `for_each`, but on elements within a resource, instead of the resource itself.

It has an example which gets close to what I am trying to do, but not quite:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tfenvtest" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftest.name}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.11.4 running Go 1.12.6"

  dynamic "setting" {
    for_each = var.settings
    content {
      namespace = setting.value["namespace"]
      name = setting.value["name"]
      value = setting.value["value"]
    }
  }
}
```

But I need for both the **key** and the value to be grabbed from the variable.  This is because I am trying to use Terraform for GCP's Cloud Composer (Airflow Environment), and [its template looks like](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-pypi) this:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "example" {
  name = "example-environment"
  region = "us-central1"

  config {

    software_config {
      pypi_packages = {
          scipy = ">=1.10.3"
          scikit-learn = ""
          nltk = "[machine_learning]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, I want to be able to make a configurable list of the packages to install.  I tried something like:

```
locals {
  python_packages = {
    "mylocalpackage" = ">=0.3.3"
    "pandas" = ">=1.0"
  }
}
resource "google_composer_environment" "composer" {
  name = "${data.google_project.env.project_id}-composer"
  .
  .
  .
  config {
    software_config {
      image_version = var.image_version
      dynamic "pypi_packages" {
        for_each = var.python_packages
        content {
          pypi_packages.key = pypi_packages.value
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

But this is not possible because Terraform does not allow for variables to be used on the left-side of an assignment.  In other words, the line that breaks things is:

```
  pypi_packages.key = pypi_packages.value
```

specifically because the `pypi_packages.key` is not allowed on the left side of the `=`. But then how can I use variables to make the assignment that the resource template requires?

---

## Summary

How can I add Python packages to my GCP Composer environment using variables?

Comment: Does `"${pypi_packages.key}" = pypi_packages.value` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the actual issue here is that you are attempting to use dynamic blocks with a parameter/argument. You could use a dynamic block with `software_config` as it is a block, but `pypi_packages` is not a block but rather a parameter that expects a value of type `map(string)`. Since `var.python_packages` is already that type and is assigned the expected values then we can assign it directly and avoid a dynamic block entirely:

```
resource "google_composer_environment" "composer" {
  name = "${data.google_project.env.project_id}-composer"
  ...
  config {
    software_config {
      image_version = var.image_version
      pypi_packages = var.python_packages
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I do it in this case, what should `var.python_packages` look like?  The problem is that the configuration `pypi_packages` is not _quite_ a map.  Notice the syntax: `{ key = value}`, not `{ key: value }`.  A map does not have this "A = B" structure, so I have to manipulate it to that structure, don't I?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, Matt.  I am usually in other languages, not Terraform, and didn't realize that for HCL, `{key = value}` is in fact how it describes a map.  :-(